# where can I find city contracts?

Tags: data-request, government

Where can I find full copies of city government contracts? I prefer file types that allow for searching. The city of Chicago provided access at one point but I can no longer find the actual files.

Comment: procurement contracts?

Comment: As Albert commented, what kind of contracts? And what period, what cities (size)? Please [edit], it looks like your question needs a US tag too. And note that *file types that allow for searching* is broad - even Word documents are (batch) searchable.

Comment: Make FOIA requests. Cities don't publish contracts on their own.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that it's just US cities that you are interested in, the US City Local Open Data Census records those that are open under its [procurement contracts](http://us-city.census.okfn.org/dataset/contracts) category.

So if you're looking for Chigaco, you will find the [link](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Administration-Finance/Contracts/rsxa-ify5) to the open dataset in question under the 'location' column of the table

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the contracts are listed in [this dataset](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Administration-Finance/Contracts/rsxa-ify5/data) and when available, there is a link to the PDF.